# special price - how to remove in mass?

Tags: magento

I hase set some special price, with a start date, and no end date.
Now I want to remove all the special price.
so no discount.

I went to the catalog view, I select ALL products, and clicked on "change attributes".
I've check the "updated" checkbox beside start date, and special price.
then I click apply.

I can see the special price disappeared, but... on the front end, I can still see the promotion!
How is it possible?
Now note that If I select a product on the backoffice, and If I click on "save" (without editing anything) then it works on the front end!!

Of course I re-indexed everything and cleared the cache.
I have 20k products so I cannot select all products one by one to click on "save"

thaks for your help
Rod

Comment: Are you sure the cache has been cleared? Maybe there's something tied to the users session or cookies for those currently viewing the site. Try on a different computer/browser (or by using incognito mode in Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

I use [magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) for this. Most bulk operations are possible here. You'll definitely need this if you say you have 20k+ products.

Outside of this solution, you'll probably have to do stuff manually, write a script to manage the mass update, or write a direct SQL statement to update this. I'd post a query here but it can be too varied because of Magento's EAV system.

Comment: i think what @electric-jesus was getting at is that Magento will often fail at bulk actions due to timeout, even when applied to just 200 products, let alone 20k..